# When create a search function, is it faster to do it frontend or backend?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm currently using node,backbone and mongo to run my app.

My question is, when user submit a search through a collection of 10,000 objects and provide a url for example.
`http://api.mysite.com/search/cards?q=king`

Is it faster to filter the data with node then add the model to the search View? Or is it faster to filter the data in Backbone then fetch the model afterwards.

Comment: Why haven't you definitively answered this for yourself by implementing both and measuring?

Comment: serverside might be faster but then if you have 1000 clients connected at the same time and searching diff things. you will have to decide which is better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will almost always be faster to do searches faster server-side, although the final result always depends on the hardware that is being tested. Doing browser-side searches also increases variability in the stability of your application because different clients have different performing machines.

As a general note, a search of ten thousand would probably freeze the browser by blocking the main thread, which you should generally avoid doing. However, moving load from the server to client can also be a good idea, depending on your application.

For server-side searching, you will have the overhead increase with the number of clients. But processing client side, you will have to use a greater amount of bandwidth and send unnecessary information.